# Java Bean Validation for two parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, bean-validation

I have two parameters `String firstName` and `String fullName`. I want to use java bean validation annotation with these parameters. The trouble is I want this validation to be conditional, if firstName is null then fullName cannot be null and vice versa. Is there anyway to do this with java bean validation?

If not, what is the best alternative? I could always do the validation in my controller, but I would my application's validation to be uniform mostly handled in our entities/model.

Currently I have the validation getting done like this

> if(firstName == null && fullName == null){
>
> throw new ValidationException("either firstName or fullName must be supplied");
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

If you have a conditional requirement between two properties in a bean, you would need to write a custom [class level constraint](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-class-level-constraints). In this case you get passed the whole bean instance into the constraint validator and can implement the conditional logic required. This solution is compliant with the Bean Validation specification and hence portable between Bean Validation implementations. A Hibernate Validator specific (non portable) solution is to use [@ScriptAssert](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/ScriptAssert.html).